# WCF - Mono server with Microsoft .NET client

Tags: .net, wcf, mono, datacontractserializer

I've got a .NET client and server that works using `NetTcpBinding` on Windows, with the Microsoft .NET Framework.

I want to allow running the server on Linux, using Mono 3.2.7. However, when the Microsoft .NET client tries to call a method on the Mono server, it get this error message:

> Unable to contact agent 192.168.0.xx: Error in deserializing body of
>   reply message for operation 'MyMethod'. The empty namespace requires a
>   null or empty prefix.
>
> The empty namespace requires a null or empty prefix.

I've hunted around but can't get any clues as to how to fix this.

*** Update ***

I just tried it with `BasicHttpBinding` instead, and again it works fine with the Microsoft .NET Framework - but it still won't work with Mono. I get a similar error to the one I get with `NetTcpBinding`:

> Cannot redefine the namespace for prefix '' used at current element

The server gives this stack trace:

```
Exception Cannot redefine the namespace for prefix '' used at current element   at System.Xml.XmlTextWriter.WriteEndAttribute () [0x0028e] in /home/user/mono/mono/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml/XmlTextWriter2.cs:995 
  at System.Xml.DefaultXmlWriter.WriteEndAttribute () [0x00000] in /home/user/mono/mono/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml/DefaultXmlWriter.cs:116 
  at System.Xml.XmlSimpleDictionaryWriter.WriteEndAttribute () [0x00000] in /home/user/mono/mono/mcs/class/System.Runtime.Serialization/System.Xml/XmlSimpleDictionaryWriter.cs:97 
  at System.Xml.XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString (System.String prefix, System.String localName, System.String ns, System.String value) [0x00025] in /home/user/mono/mono/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml/XmlWriter.cs:270 
  at System.Xml.XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString (System.String localName, System.String value) [0x00000] in /home/user/mono/mono/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml/XmlWriter.cs:254 
  at System.Xml.XmlDictionaryWriter.WriteXmlnsAttribute (System.String prefix, System.String namespaceUri) [0x00077] in /home/user/mono/mono/mcs/class/System.Runtime.Serialization/System.Xml/XmlDictionaryWriter.cs:396 
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.WriteStartObject (System.Xml.XmlDictionaryWriter writer, System.Object graph) [0x0022f] in /home/user/mono/mono/mcs/class/System.Runtime.Serialization/System.Runtime.Serialization/DataContractSerializer.cs:501 
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObject (System.Xml.XmlDictionaryWriter writer, System.Object graph) [0x00000] in /home/user/mono/mono/mcs/class/System.Runtime.Serialization/System.Runtime.Serialization/XmlObjectSerializer.cs:113 
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractMessagesFormatter+DataContractBodyWriter.WriteMessagePart (System.Xml.XmlDictionaryWriter writer, System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageBodyDescription desc, System.ServiceModel.Description.MessagePartDescription partDesc, System.Object obj) [0x00049] in /home/user/mono/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher/BaseMessagesFormatter.cs:503 
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractMessagesFormatter+DataContractBodyWriter.OnWriteBodyContents (System.Xml.XmlDictionaryWriter writer) [0x00054] in /home/user/mono/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher/BaseMessagesFormatter.cs:486 
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BodyWriter.WriteBodyContents (System.Xml.XmlDictionaryWriter writer) [0x00000] in /home/user/mono/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/BodyWriter.cs:57 
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SimpleMessage.OnWriteBodyContents (System.Xml.XmlDictionaryWriter writer) [0x00000] in /home/user/mono/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/MessageImpl.cs:331 
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.WriteBodyContents (System.Xml.XmlDictionaryWriter writer) [0x00022] in /home/user/mono/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/Message.cs:183 
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.WriteBody (System.Xml.XmlDictionaryWriter writer) [0x0001c] in /home/user/mono/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/Message.cs:168 
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.OnWriteMessage (System.Xml.XmlDictionaryWriter writer) [0x00065] in /home/user/mono/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/Message.cs:293 
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.WriteMessage (System.Xml.XmlDictionaryWriter writer) [0x00026] in /home/user/mono/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/Message.cs:195 
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoder.WriteMessage (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message, System.IO.Stream stream) [0x0004a] in /home/user/mono/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/TextMessageEncoder.cs:122 
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Http.HttpRequestContext.InternalReply (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message msg, TimeSpan timeout) [0x00034] in /home/user/mono/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels.Http/HttpRequestContext.cs:139 
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Http.HttpRequestContext.Reply (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message msg, TimeSpan timeout) [0x00000] in /home/user/mono/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels.Http/HttpRequestContext.cs:101 
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageProcessingContext.Reply (Boolean useTimeout) [0x00026] in /home/user/mono/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher/MessageProcessingContext.cs:96 
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationInvokerHandler.Reply (System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageProcessingContext mrc, Boolean useTimeout) [0x0001d] in /home/user/mono/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher/OperationInvokerHandler.cs:69 
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationInvokerHandler.ProcessRequest (System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageProcessingContext mrc) [0x00044] in /home/user/mono/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher/OperationInvokerHandler.cs:29 
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.BaseRequestProcessorHandler.ProcessRequestChain (System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageProcessingContext mrc) [0x00000] in /home/user/mono/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher/BaseRequestProcessorHandler.cs:15 
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.BaseRequestProcessorHandler.ProcessRequestChain (System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageProcessingContext mrc) [0x00017] in /home/user/mono/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher/BaseRequestProcessorHandler.cs:16 
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.HandlersChain.ProcessRequestChain (System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageProcessingContext mrc) [0x0000b] in /home/user/mono/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher/BaseRequestProcessor.cs:72 
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.BaseRequestProcessor.ProcessRequest (System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageProcessingContext mrc) [0x00018] in /home/user/mono/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher/BaseRequestProcessor.cs:26
```

It's obviously something related to serialisation, but more than that I don't know.

I've fired up Wireshark to see what the data looks like on the wire, and the HTTP POST sent to the Windows server and the Mono server look exactly the same.

Comment: On Mono you should be careful about which framework to choose from. For example, Web API is better supported than WCF, NHibernate better than EF. This is due to the open source nature, not really a bias on frameworks. Had the Mono guys enough resources, they should be able to make everything working.

Comment: WCF has been around a lot longer than Web API, so I would have thought it would work even with the basic HTTP binding without security :(  I'm already using WCF on Windows, so it wouldn't be ideal to add Web API too. Plus I need the service to be self-hosted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were 2 parts to getting this working (annoyingly, both of which are required *only* by Mono - not by Microsoft .NET):

1. Set IsReference to true on the `DataContract` attribute on classes you will send on the wire:
   `[DataContract(IsReference = true)]`
2. Do *not* set a namespace on the `DataContract` attribute on those classes

Comment: I should add that this is without transport or message security, which I've been unable to get working with certificates and NetTcpBinding or BasicHttpBinding. I concede defeat and completely give up on Mono :`(